# HELP!! What is this bike frame?

Tags: frames, triathlon, time-trial

[image]

Hello all, I've won this triathlon frame on Ebay for £150 but have yet to pay. Apparently Vision have never made frames and deal only in components (according to their customer service). Is this some sort of fake? I bought as I felt that I could sell the headset, make back some of the money spent and then just use the frame and forks for a Triathlon build but now I'm worried that the CK headset may be a fugazy as well. It should be noted though that the seller has good reviews on other bikes sold within the past 6 months at a similar price. Any help and insight is appreciated. Stay blessed

Comment: My guess is that it's a far east manufactured frame sold under several short lived 'brands' online. Not related to https://www.visiontechusa.com/ but not a intentional fake.

Comment: They do seem to be Italian colours in the logo, maybe a lead

Comment: I think if you are looking for evidence that this is a counterfeit so you can get out of paying after winning the auction you are going to be disappointed - unless the seller explicitly made a claim that this was made by the Vision components company.

Comment: I'll note that the logo is not the same one used by the Vision component manufacturer.

Comment: @Swifty I thought of that, sadly googling "vision italy/italian" found nothing of pertinence.Thanks

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus he did list the brand as Vision in the item description, but I suspect you may be right. I do want the frame for this dirt cheap Tri build so, have you or anyone else experience with one of these far eastern imitations? W

Comment: The welding looks of comparable quality to the joins On a Jamis Ventura 2018 I picked up second hand. https://www.evanscycles.com/jamis-ventura-comp-2018-road-bike-EV306033. At least I think.....

Comment: @Will I don’t think it’s an imitation of anything, someone just randomly chose ‘Vision’ to slap on the side

Comment: @DanielRHicks Damn....well, more fool me right? Here's hoping it actually turns out not to be cack.

Comment: It could be a demo / show frame that was used for marketing the parts. I have seen frames with Shimano decals that were used this way. Still, if the bike is cheap and seller doesn't have any paperwork or even idea what they are selling, it's likely it's fake or stolen. My recommendation would be to do the homework before committing money.